# Questions on differentiability

Tags: measure-theory

I am considering a function $F: (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as ($t>0$):

$$F(t)=\int_{(0,\infty)} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{-tx}$$

I am asked to show that $F$ is differentiable and to find an expression for $F'(t)$.

**My attempt:**

I have used what my book calls the "differentiablity lemma":

Define $u(t,x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{-tx}$

1) I have shown that $\int_{(0,\infty)} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{-tx} <\infty$ and (with measurability) therefore $u \in \mathcal{L}^1(\lambda)$

2) I have shown that $F$ is differentiable with $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(t,x)=e^{-tx}\sin(x)$

3) Putting $w(t)=1$ I have shown that $\vert e^{-tx}\sin(x) \vert \leq 0$. Furthermore $w(t)=1$ is continuous and therefore measurable and if I can show that $\int_{(0,\infty)}w(t) \, d\lambda = \int_{(0,\infty)} 1 \, d\lambda<  \infty$ (**NOT SURE**) then I can conclude that $w(t) \in \mathcal{L}^{1}(\lambda)$.

The "differentiability lemma" says that if 1),2) and 3) are satisfied then the the function $F$ is differentiable and the derivative is $\int_{(0,\infty)}u(t,x) d\lambda(x)$ (which I have not calculated yet).

Could someone give some feedback about the "NOT SURE" part. Much appreciated!

Comment: There is a difference between these two things: $$ \begin{align} & \int_{(0,\infty)} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{-tx} \, dx \\ {} \\ & \int_{(0,\infty)} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{-tx} \, dt \end{align} $$ so explicitness is not a bad thing. (And there are other reasons too.)

Comment: I'm sorry to say that, but in (3) most things are nonsense or just false.

Comment: Michael Hardy, Indeed! In 1) I am simply trying to show that $u \in \mathcal{L}^{1}(\lambda)$ so I should have written $\int_{(0,\infty)}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{-tx} d\lambda$. Could you comment on 3) and the "NOTE SURE" part.

Comment: amsmath, for $w(t)=1$ it should say that $\vert e^{-tx} \sin(x)\vert \leq 1 $. That was a mistake. Furthermore I would like to show the "NOT SURE" part. Other than I do not see any mistakes. But feel free to correct me.

Comment: I assume the integral in the first displayed equation should have a $\mathsf dx$?

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, Mathematica tells me that the derivative is given by
$$
-\frac1{1+t^2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

It's an application of the Leibniz integral rule, but it's no harder to do it from scratch:

$\frac{F(t+h)-F(t)}{h}=\int_{(0,\infty)} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\frac{e^{-tx}(e^{-hx}-1)}{h}dx.$ Set $h=1/n$, so that $\frac{F(t+h)-F(t)}{h}=\int_{(0,\infty)} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{-tx}\cdot n(e^{-x/n}-1)dx.$

Now $n(e^{-x/n}-1)\to -x$ as $n\to \infty$ so the dominated convergence theorem implies that $F'(t)=-\int_{(0,\infty)}e^{-tx} \sin xdx=-\frac{1}{t^2+1}.$ The integral is cyclic and so was easy to calculate by hand.

Comment: Appreciate the response. Could you provide som feedback on $\int_{(0,\infty)} 1 d\lambda < \infty$? This seems impossible.

Comment: Where are you seeing this integral? It is not anywhere in my answer. And you are right, it diverges.